# jQuery onLoad Textbox update

Tags: jquery

I have the following code, I want the function to execute on load.

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
var runningRequest = false;
var request;

$('input#asd3').on('load input change propertychange onpaste', function(e) {

    var $q = $(this);
    if($q.val.length == 12){


        return false;
    }

    if(runningRequest){
        request.abort();
    }
    runningRequest=true;

    var myString = self.location.href;
    var mySplitResult = myString.split("?");

    request = $.getJSON('apisearch?t=usr',{q:$q.val()},function(data){  
        showResults2(data,$q.val());         
        showResultsrecruit(data,$q.val());
        showResultsaddress(data,$q.val());
        showResultseducation(data,$q.val());
        showResultshigheducation(data,$q.val());
        showResultsexperience(data,$q.val());
        showResultselections(data,$q.val());            
        runningRequest=false;

    });
    ...
```

The PHP.

```
$mykad = ''.htmlentities($_GET['mykad']).'';
```

The HTML:

```
echo '<input type="text" id="asd3" name="asd3" value="'.$mykad.'"  class="form-control" autocomplete="on" placeholder="Enter 12 digit MyKad..." class="input-block-level" autofocus="autofocus" placeholder="Search Mykad..." maxlength="12" style="width:90%;" />';
```

It gets the value of the mykad in the textbox which is then suppose to execute the search function.

It works perfectly, if I change the textbox, on click on focus etc. But it doesn't execute on page load.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var runningRequest = false;
var request;
 var $q = $('input#asd3');
function toexecute($q) {
    request = $.getJSON('apisearch?t=usr',{q:$q.val()},function(data){  
        showResults2(data,$q.val());         
        showResultsrecruit(data,$q.val());
        showResultsaddress(data,$q.val());
        showResultseducation(data,$q.val());
        showResultshigheducation(data,$q.val());
        showResultsexperience(data,$q.val());
        showResultselections(data,$q.val());            
        runningRequest=false;

    });
}
 toexecute($q);
$('input#asd3').on('load input change propertychange onpaste', function(e) {

    var $q = $(this);
   if($q.val.length == 12){


        return false;
    }

    if(runningRequest){
        request.abort();
    }
    runningRequest=true;

    var myString = self.location.href;
    var mySplitResult = myString.split("?");
     toexecute($q)
    });
    ...
```